# Weird error deploying django on apache, mod_wsgi, debian

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

on django 1.8
In apache error logs am getting

```
File "..../python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/lru_cache.py", line 28
fasttypes = {int, str, frozenset, type(None)},
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

googling around this seems to be an error you get when running django 1.7+ and not meeting the minimum python requirement of 2.7.
however

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.3
```

here is the relevant parts of apache virtual host config.

```
<VirtualHost <some_ip>:80>       
        WSGIDaemonProcess some_process python-path=/path/to/django-project/main-django-app:/path/to/virtual-env/site-packages/ threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}
        WSGIProcessGroup some_group

        WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/django-project/main-django-app/wsgi.py

        <Directory /path/to/django-project/main-django-app>
        <Files wsgi.py>
                Order deny,allow

                # Require all granted
                # for Apache < 2.4
                Allow from all
        </Files>
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

does anyone have any idea what the issue might be?

Comment: Doesn't matter what the command line Python version is. The mod_wsgi package is compiled for a specific Python version and links in the Python shared library. Thus isn't using 'python' from PATH. Your mod_wsgi is likely compiled for Python 2.6. See the documentation http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation#Python_Shared_Library and http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation#Python_Installation_In_Use

Comment: right on the button. The default on this system is 2.6.6 (its a managed server and i forgot i had a locally compiled version of 2.7 i was using). I'm waiting to see if recompiling mod_wsgi to 2.7 resolves this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the mod_wsgi for your python version.

If you have not access to the apache installation, mod_wsgi can be installed directly in your virtualenv using pip. Then it can be loaded in your server settings using:

Global settings:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /path/to_your_env/path/to/mod_wsgi.so
WSGISocketPrefix run/wsgi
WSGIDaemonProcess 385969
```

Virtualhost:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / "/path/to/your/wsgi.py"
<Location />
    WSGIProcessGroup 385969 # this value must be identical to WSGIDaemonProcess
</Location>
```

Finally, I your wsgi.py file, you'll have to activate the virtualenv.